# PATH issues for init.d scripts on startup

Tags: ubuntu, init.d, path

I have a simple script that starts up a unicorn instance (on Ubuntu 12.04LTS).

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    start)
       echo "starting"
       cd /path && bundle exec unicorn -c /path/config/unicorn.rb -D -E production
      ;;
     stop)
      echo "Stopping Unicorn Instances"
      kill `cat /tmp/unicorn.pid`
    ;;
    restart)
    echo "sending USR2 to all unicorns"
    kill -s USR2 `cat /tmp/unicorn.pid`
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

It behaves correctly when called: `/etc/init.d/unicorn_boot.sh start`

I want it to start on boot, so I ran:
`update-rc.d -f unicorn_boot.sh defaults`

When I now reboot I get the following error:

`/etc/rc2.d/S20unicorn_boot.sh: 10: /etc/rc2.d/S20unicorn_boot.sh: bundle: not found`

I checked the `bundle` command, and it's installed in `/usr/local/bin`, same for the `ruby` command.

It appears that on boot the `PATH` does not yet include `/usr/local/bin`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initscripts are responsible for setting an appropriate path themselves. Set the `$PATH` variable at the top of the script:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't know that. It's fixed now!

Comment: Alternatively you should be able to set `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` to append your required paths to the variable, rather than overriding the $PATH variable entirely.

Comment: Relying on an outside $PATH is a security risk.  Don't append an existing PATH!  Create your own with the exact list you need.