# How to run an init.d script to run after $PATH is set

Tags: init.d, path

I created an init.d script that launches a system daemon. The daemon uses the system $PATH to launch other processes. The system path, however, does not include "/usr/local/bin" at the time the init.d loads the daemon. So, I have to stop/start the init.d daemon after reboot, which really defeats the purpose of the init.d script!

This question says the init.d script should set the path. [PATH issues for init.d scripts on startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/481685/path-issues-for-init-d-scripts-on-startup)

Although this is possible, I'd like a little more flexibility. Is it possible to force the init.d script to load at a runlevel after the system sets the $PATH variable?

Comment: Why not update PATH in your script to include /usr/local/bin ? e.g. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the path is changed during init, rather it's that normal shells get a different environment. See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Path-4.html for an explanation.

Either set the path explicitly at the top of your script or create a new script to set the path and source that at the top of scripts that need the changed environment.